# Read Excel values with powershell ​in array listed one by one with comma separation

Tags: arrays, excel, powershell

I found the following code and I want to modify it slightly. unfortunately the output is not read into a real array. [Excel Reading to Powershell Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047829/excel-reading-to-powershell-array)

[image]

I then run through the array(s) with a for each loop and write a new Emailsent value (date + time) if necessary.

How can I adapt the code from the link so that it writes the values ​​one after the other with a comma, so that I can format the array again with $Emailssent[$i] = get-date - format g ((get-Date).Addhours(1) ) can address?

Comment: What does the values from the excel file have to do with `Get-Date -Format`? You can run the latter without any input

Comment: In my script I want to insert a new value (getdate + 1 hour) into the array imported from Excel. But I only know how to address the consecutively listed arrays separated by commas (see picture) with $Emailssent[$i] = Get-date -format g ((Get-Date).AddHours(1))